# check for last row in for loop plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using FOR Loop in plsql for students and departments and storing department names in log table separated by commas, but I get extra ',' after last department name how to remove it?

```
For i IN
 (select (DEPT_NAME) DeptName FROM TBL_DEPT WHERE PREV_DEPT_NAME = 
lPrevDeptName)
LOOP
 lNewDept := lNewDept || i.DeptName || ',';

...
.....
....
END LOOP;
```

and I am updating log table with new deptname at last, but i am getting result like 'IT,HR,Accounts,' in log table, want to remove extra ',' after Accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RTRIM` it:

```
lNewDept := rtrim(lNewDept, ',');
```

For example:

```
SQL> with test (lNewDept) as (select 'IT,HR,Accounts,' from dual)
  2  select rtrim(lNewDept, ',') result
  3  from test;

RESULT
--------------
IT,HR,Accounts

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
For i IN
 (select (DEPT_NAME) DeptName FROM TBL_DEPT WHERE PREV_DEPT_NAME = 
lPrevDeptName)
LOOP

 if lNewDept is null then
   lNewDept := i.DeptName
 else
   lNewDept := lNewDept || ',' ||i.DeptName;
 end if;

...
.....
....
END LOOP;
```